# Want to have a class store a vector of smart pointers to an abstract class. ("cannot instantiate abstract class")

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, c++17, abstract-class

I want to have a class containing a vector of shared pointers to an abstract class, which on runtime will be derived class objects. Here's the abstract class: (I found a workaround. It's in the comments).

```
#pragma once
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

using std::string_view; using std::string;
class Someone
{
private:
    string _name;
    unsigned _skill;

protected:
    Someone (string_view name, unsigned skill) : _name{ name }, _skill{ skill }
    { }

    Someone (const Someone& another) : _name{ another._name }, _skill{ another._skill }
    { }

    virtual ~Someone () = default;
public:

    string_view getName () const { return string_view (_name); }
    Someone& setName (string_view name) { _name = name; return *this; }

    unsigned getSkill () const { return _skill; }
    Someone& setSkill (unsigned skill) { _skill = skill; return *this; }

    string who () const { return "Name:" + _name + " has a skill level of " + std::to_string (_skill); }

    virtual string_view play () const = 0;//pure virtual function
};
```

Bellow, are the two simple Derived classes:

```
#pragma once
#include "Someone.h"
class Newbie : public Someone
{
public:
    Newbie (string_view name, unsigned skill) : Someone (name, skill)
    { }

    Newbie (const Newbie& another) : Someone (another)
    { }

    virtual string_view play () const override { return "Meh"; }
};
```

And

```
#pragma once
#include "Someone.h"
class Pro : public Someone
{
public:
    Pro (string_view name, unsigned skill) : Someone (name, skill)
    { }

    Pro (const Pro& another) : Someone (another)
    { }

    virtual string_view play () const override { return "Wow!"; }
};
```

And here's the class the causes the errors. As soon as I uncomment any of the push_back lines, I get the error "Someone:" cannot instantiate abstract class.

```
class Everyone
{
private:
    vector<shared_ptr<Someone>> _roster;
public:

    Everyone () = default;

    Everyone (const Someone& first)
    {
        _roster.push_back (make_shared<Someone> (first));
    }

    Everyone (initializer_list<Someone> all)
    {
        for (const Someone& one : all)
        {
            //_roster.push_back (make_shared<Someone> (one));
        }
    }

    Everyone& addSomeone (const Someone& someone)
    {
        //_roster.push_back (make_shared<Someone> (someone));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: `make_shared<Someone>` is the problem, since it creates an instance of an abstract class. The rest is irrelevant.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know statically what `Someone` type the argument points to. You can either make `addSomeone(auto const& someone)` a function template or you can equip your `Someone` class with a [pure] `virtual` function to create a clone and return it as a suitable [smart] pointer.

Comment: You cannot create instances of an abstract class.

Comment: So the pointer has to come ready from the caller... that would be a solution, right? @UlrichEckhardt if I make the methods in Everyone accept shared_ptr<Someone> it works. Final doubt, should I receive those parameters as const references?

Comment: That would be a solution indeed. I would suggest taking `unique_ptr`, not `shared_ptr`. You can then transform them into `shared_ptr`, but please think carefully about it. Most of the time, `shared_ptr` can be avoided

Comment: @G'k I will learn ```unique_ptr``` soon, I hope. For now, I created a pair of methods in both ```Newbie``` and ```Pro``` classes (with the corresponding types):
```std::shared_ptr<Newbie> toPtr () const { return std::make_shared<Newbie> (*this); }```
And this static one at each class:
```static std::shared_ptr<Newbie> MakePtr (string_view name, unsigned skill) { return std::make_shared<Newbie> (name, skill); }```

Although I believe my ```toPtr``` instance method uses the copy constructor, i.e., creates a copy of ```*this```.

Comment: You might be interested in [this blog post](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/08/make-polymorphic-copy-modern-cpp/)